# accessing local variables within another function

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have written:

```
function p_deal(id) {
    var card1_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var card2_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
        var card1 = deck[card1_val];
        var card2 = deck[card2_val];
    var hand = card1 + ", " + card2;
var res = card1_val + card2_val;

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = hand;
```

and

```
function hit(id) {
    if (bucket == 0) {
        bucket = " ";
    }

    var card3_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var nhand = deck[card3_val];
    bucket = bucket + " " + nhand + ", ";
    bucket_val = bucket_val + card1_val + card2_val + card3_val;

    if (bucket_val >= 22) {
        var r = confirm("Bust! By " + nhand);
        if (r == true) {
            refresh();
        }
        else {
            refresh();
        }
    }

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = bucket;

    light = light + 1;

    if (light == 5) {
        alert("Five Card Blackjack! You Win!");
        refresh();
    }
}
```

The card_val variables within bucket val are from the p_deal(id) function. In order for the program to work, the card_val values must be the **same** each time both functions are called but they need to be regenerated each time the function is called (so multiple players can have different hands). However, as local variables I find it difficult to use them in another function.  What can i do here?

Comment: You might want to find a better way of "shuffling" the deck than `Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length)`. Might I suggest shuffling the deck?

Comment: @Eric--could you elaborate some more? Do you have any ideas on how to better shuffle the deck?

Comment: You method of "shuffling" can pick the same card twice in a row. Instead, you should sort the deck in a random order, as in a real shuffle. The best way of doing this is to use a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). To draw a card, simply [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) off the top card of the shuffled array.

Comment: @Eric--I thought about doing that, but the problem is that I have attached conditional statements that define the face cards as values:

`if (card1 == "Jack") {
  card1_val = 10;
 }
 else if (card1 == "Queen") {
  card1_val = 10;
 }
 else if (card1 == "King") {
  card1_val = 10;
 }
 else if (card1 == "Ace") {
  card1_val = 11;
 }
`

I didn't know how else to make sure the faces were treated as values.

How can I combine both approaches?

Comment: [Create a class for each card as well!](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/8JzCE/)

Comment: @Eric--A very elegant solution. Simple yet powerful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want an object:

```
function Hand(id) {
    this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
    this.bucket = "";
    this.bucketVal = 0;
    this.deal = function() {
        this.card1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
        this.card2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
        this.elem.innerHTML = deck[this.card1] + ', ' + this.card2;
    }
    this.hit = function() {

        var newCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
        this.bucket += " " + deck[nhand] + ", ";
        this.bucketVal += this.card1 + this.card2 + newCard;

        if (this.bucketVal >= 22) {
            var r = confirm("Bust! By " + nhand);

            refresh();
        }

        this.elem.innerHTML = this.bucket;

        light = light + 1;

        if (light == 5) {
            alert("Five Card Blackjack! You Win!");
            refresh();
        }
    }
}

var player1Hand = new Hand('player1Id');
player1Hand.deal();
player1Hand.hit();
```

Comment: @Eric--I don't know much about OOP. Can you break down this approach?

Comment: @codeninja: Are you having difficulty with the syntax, or just the concepts?

Comment: @Eric--its been a while since i commented on this thread, i hope you get this comment.

what i don't understand about this approach is that hit() is embedded within Hand(id). doesn't that mean i cannot call hit independently? Please explain.

Comment: `hit()` becomes part of the `Hand` class. Any instance of a `Hand` class contains the `hit` method. My code shows an example of how to `hit` player 1.

Comment: @Eric--I got it, i didnt see that part of the code. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

easy way: make them global or pass them between the functions

harder but more advisable way: use objects instead and make those variable attributes of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Make them global variables rather than local variables.